# install xmlrpc for c++ in /usr/local/lib

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, installation, xml-rpc

I want to use [xml-rpc for C and C++](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/) in a project. I was able to configure and make (build) the project correctly, however, i need the library to be installed in `/usr/local/lib` , `/usr/local/include` . When i run `make install` the library will be installed in `/usr/lib` , `/usr/include`.
Can anybody help, i.e. explain how to install the library in the other directory.

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

you need to build it with : `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/` && `make` && `make install`.

Anyway, the best solution is probably to install it via the package manager of the distribution you are using.

Comment: thank you i will try this. I also tried to install the package via the package manager, hower the package manager will also install it into /usr/lib, /usr/include.

Comment: yeah , package manager will surely install in /usr, but do you really need a version that is not packaged yet ? Or why do you absolutely want it in /usr/local ?

Comment: because later the application will be compiled on different platforms. i need it to build from source. Btw.: if i intall the library using `make install`, how would i uninstall it again, i cannot find a `make uninstall` or something like that?